# Get file contents from Ractive on-change event

Tags: javascript, filereader, ractivejs

I'm trying to get the headers of a CSV file I've attached to a file input. I fire a function on change of the file input and check if there are any files in the event and then start a FileReader onload so I can get the contents but the onload function doesn't get fired. Is there something I'm missing?

```
Ractive.on('getHeaders', function(target) {
  // Check that the file is a file
  if(target.node.files !== undefined) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var headers = [];

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the files to the reader, like this:

```
Ractive.on('getHeaders', function(target) {
  // Check that the file is a file
  if(target.node.files !== undefined) {

    var headers = [];
    target.node.files.forEach(function(file){

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(reader.result);
    };

   reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   });      
  }
});
```